# Is it possible to rollback sqlite3 changes after commit in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm calling these functions via tkinter button click. So once the commit is done, if i need to revert changes I'm calling doing rollback but its not reverting the changes

```
def insert(_id,name,phone):
              conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
              print ("Opened database successfully");
              print (name,phone)
              conn.execute("INSERT INTO VARUN (ID,NAME,PHONE) \
                    VALUES (?,?,?)",(_id,name,phone));
              conn.commit()
              print ("New record(s)" , name," has just been added to the database");
              conn.close()


def rollback():

    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    conn.rollback()
    print ("\n changes reverted")
    conn.close()
```

Comment: You may want to look into what [ACID Compliance](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-db/transactions/acid.html) means. Commit and rollback are not "point in time" records of the state of the database. They control individual *transactions*, which represent a set of queries executed in sequence. In particular, "committing" one means, "make all data changes final and available to all future transactions."

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Once a transaction has committed, all changes are merged in the database, and are indistinguishable from other data.

If you want to revert changes later, you have to store not only the changed result but also enough information to restore the changes in the database.
See [Automatic Undo/Redo Using SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/undoredo.html) for an example.